# how i can write test virus?

Tags: website, anti-virus, malware, upload

i have a website and in website some people can upload files .... and when user upload file it must scan from virus by antivirus ... so i need test virus have the following extention (.doc ,jpg, png, jpeg, gif, doc, docx, pdf, xls, xlsx ) to sure the antivirus work correctly

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Get the [EICAR test vector](http://www.eicar.org/anti_virus_test_file.htm) and use that.

Comment: i try it but when i test it it give me the mime file invalied ???

Comment: Try another location to download it from.

Comment: i try but the problem is when the website check the header of the file it reject it ... maybe when but the code of EICAR he convert it to binary code

Comment: file->save as...or find a site from an AV vendor that lets you download it as a zip or other format (like text, since it's just a text string) and save it as such.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EICAR_test_file

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to download it.  Just open up notepad and paste the following into the file:

```
X5O!P%@AP[4\PZX54(P^)7CC)7}$EICAR-STANDARD-ANTIVIRUS-TEST-FILE!$H+H*
```

Then, save it as whatever file you want.  You'll probably need to temporarily turn off your AV to handle the file though.

This comes from the EICAR Anti Malware Test file page: https://www.eicar.org/?page_id=3950

Answer (score 1):

You could download the [EICAR test virus](http://www.eicar.org/anti_virus_test_file.htm) pattern to a file and rename the extension to what you need.

Comment: i try it but when i test it it give me the mime file invalied ???